# Insert data to a specific column

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have two tables, one is `Info` and another is `WorkDetails`.

Table Info: `ID(PK), Name, Weather, Date, Status, TimeIn_Info, TimeOut_Info`

Table WorkDetails: `ID(PK),Project,WorkDescription,Per,TimeIn,TimeOut // 4 row`

How can I insert the d value to the TimeOut and TimeOut_Info which are in two different tables when button is clicked?

```
public void checkRow3(String a, String b, String c, String d) {
    if(!d.equals("null")) {
        WD.insertWorkDetails(a3, a, b, c, d); // working fine
        db.execSQL("INSERT into" + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO + "(TimeOut_Info) values(?);", new String[]{d}); //insert d to Table Info column TableOut_Info
        Toast.makeText(this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to implement?

**MyDatabaseHelper.java**

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_INFO + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,Name TEXT,Weather TEXT, Date DATETIME, Status Text, TimeIn_Info DATE TIME, TimeOut_Info DATETIME)");
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_WORKDETAILS + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , Project TEXT, WorkDescription TEXT, Per Text, TimeIn DATETIME, TimeOut DATETIME)");
    }
```

**Edited**

I changed to this, but still no luck

```
 if (!(TextUtils.isEmpty(d)))
        {
            WD.insertWorkDetails(a3, a, b, c, d);
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO" +MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO+"(TimeOut_Info) VALUES (d)");


        }
```

**Error**

```
10-12 07:32:07.942    4814-4814/com.example.project.project E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 4814
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.project.project.WorkDetailsTable.checkRow3(WorkDetailsTable.java:235)
            at com.example.project.project.WorkDetailsTable$1$1.onClick(WorkDetailsTable.java:178)
            at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:153)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change
`db.execSQL("INSERT INTO" +MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO+"(TimeOut_Info) VALUES (d)");`

To

```
 db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.TimeOut_Info, d);
 db.insert(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO, null, values);
```

Everytime you want to insert or update your database, remember write this statement  `db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();`

Answer (score 0):

Create methods for inserting data for both tables and call both.

Comment: Is it possible to add the data into a specific column only?

Comment: Yes.But for that,you have to write a WHERE clause with the id or whatever the identifier is.

Comment: @Jas that's not a correct way of inserting data into specific columns

Comment: `INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);`

Comment: Then use INSERT INTO table_name (column1) VALUES (value1); as @mangusta says

Comment: @John doesn't matter, as far as you've specified default values for columns

Comment: db.execSQL("INSERT into" + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO + "(TimeOut_Info) values(d);

Comment: Get this error  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.project.project.WorkDetailsTable.checkRow3